# Execute SSRS Report from C# save as PDF

Tags: c#, reporting-services

So, here's my delema.

The title says it all. I cannot seem to find any guidance on how to execute a SSRS report remotely and save it as a PDF.

I have tried to follow the below article.
[Using Reporting Services (SSRS) as a reference in an ASP.NET Core site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036903/using-reporting-services-ssrs-as-a-reference-in-an-asp-net-core-site)

However, when I add the Service Reference to my project some of the methods seem to have the wrong signatures.

For example.
rsExec.LoadReportAsync(report, null);

in my reference the first parameter is a TrustedUserHeader object.

Does anyone have a good starting point on how to execute an SSRS report from C#? I cannot find any simple example.

Comment: This may be an XY problem.  Why would you need to execute a report from C#?   Is this an unattended process?   Does it happen on a schedule?   Is there some reason an SSRS subscription does not suit your needs?

Comment: @TabAlleman Can you have guide me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020793/asp-net-core-download-ssrs-reports-in-pdf-format-on-client-browser-by-its-url

Comment: Are you able find out any solution? @Jcircio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do this by using Microsoft.Reporting.Webforms and the following method:

```
 using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
 ...
 public byte[] ExportToExcel(string reportName, string[] paramNames, string[][] paramDic)
    {
        // Variables
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;



        ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer { ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote };
        rv.AsyncRendering = false;
        ServerReport sr = rv.ServerReport;
        sr.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<server>/reportserver");
        sr.ReportPath = "/<report path>/" + reportName;

        if (paramNames.Length != 0)
        {
            List<ReportParameter> paramList = paramNames.Select((t, i) => new ReportParameter(t, paramDic[i])).ToList();
            rv.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
        }

        return rv.ServerReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension,
            out streamIds, out warnings);
    }
```

The `byte` array can then be sent to the client via `Response` or saved to a file to be emailed/transferred later.

The first parameter is the name of the report, the second is an array of parameter names, and the third is an array of arrays containing the parameter values. I wrote this method early in my career and I wouldn't write it this way now. If you use this, I would refactor the code to take two parameters: reportName and a Dictionary called parameters or something like that to manage the parameter values.

Comment: Hi, tried this in Asp.Net Core but not working, can you guide me on the same?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no .net core version of Microsoft.Reporting.Webforms. I'd look into a third party library like this one for .net core and RS: https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer/tree/master/AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.NetCore

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into it